# Difference in dates as days and hours

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

Need some help with trigger. I want to get the difference between two dates as days & hours.

Ex: the output should read as "2days 4hours"

```
create or replace trigger "REFRESH_TASKS_01_T"
before
insert or update or delete on "REFRESH_TASKS_01"
for each row
DECLARE
  v_date timestamp; 
  BEGIN
  IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
    :NEW.DURATION := :NEW.END_DATE-:NEW.START_DATE; 
   END IF;
end;
/
```

Comment: Triggers don't really do output. Is REFRESH_TASKS_01.DURATION a varchar2 column that you want to populate? This would make more sense as a [virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1).

Comment: Actually this trigger will update a column in my database

Comment: In that case it would be better as a virtual column. No trigger required.